# How to use a NuGet package within a PowerShell script?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I'm writing a PowerShell script that makes use of the [Mono.Cecil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil) library. How would I install the package so I can use it from within the script? Thanks!

(For the record, I did try Googling before asking this, but all that came up was results about [PMC](http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Manager-Console) and Visual Studio, which aren't relevant to this question.)

Answer (score -22, accepted):

Unable to find a good solution, I ended up just downloading and unzipping the package manually via the NuGet API.

For those who are interested/others who have this problem, [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/Shims.Xaml/blob/36eaf8b34a52cffa041d18a9c6f7187d173ec31b/generate.ps1#L60-L79) is the code I used.

Comment: "I gave up" doesn't really qualify as an answer, and certainly not as the accepted answer. At best it belongs as a comment, so that the question appears to remain unanswered (and can be found by people who might know what to do).

Comment: @Tullo_x86: the accepted mark is entirely up to the question asker, always. This does qualify as an answer, because it attempts to suggest a solution. We can use voting to indicate how helpful we think it is as an answer.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to install a package in PowerShell 6 (Core) by specifying the source:

```
PS > install-package gudusoft.gsqlparser -source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
```

Answer (score 10):

~5.x versions of PowerShell have a nuget package source included by default but it doesn't work:

```
PS > Get-PackageSource 
Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
```

If you `Unregister-PackageSource -Source nuget.org` and `Register-PackageSource -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -name nuget.org -Trusted` I have been able to install nuget papckages with just `Install-Package` from PowerShell, not within visual studio. Got the idea from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345128/101679).

I don't know what other possible negative impacts there are to removing the v3 version of the nuget.org source but I have been running this way for a while and things appear ok, your mileage may vary.

As an alternative here is an example that gets the job done by pulling down the nuget.exe even if it is a crummy way to have to do this:

```
function Install-InvokeOracleSQL {
    $ModulePath = (Get-Module -ListAvailable InvokeSQL).ModuleBase
    Set-Location -Path $ModulePath

    if ($PSVersionTable.Platform -ne "Unix") {
        $SourceNugetExe = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
        $TargetNugetExe = ".\nuget.exe"
        Invoke-WebRequest $sourceNugetExe -OutFile $targetNugetExe
        .\nuget.exe install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
        Remove-Item -Path $TargetNugetExe
    } elseif ($PSVersionTable.Platform -eq "Unix") {
        nuget install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Version 2.12.0-beta2
    }
}
```

Comment: `Unregister-PackageSource` **`-Source`** `nuget.org`

Comment: @JoshGust Name appears to be aliased as `Unregister-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -WhatIf` seems to work but `-Source` is more correct so I have edited the answer.

Comment: I found that `Register-PackageSource nugetV2 https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet` followed by `install-package` _packageName_ `-Source nugetV2` got me there without having to unregister anything.  @JamesKo I did have to manually do `add-type -path` _longPathName_ - I wasn't sure how much of this you expected to be automatic.  `Get-Package` will show you where it got installed (and it does get unpacked automatically).  And if you want to run without admin privs include `-Scope CurrentUser`