# Cannot get all versions of specific package using Find-Package

Tags: powershell

I used the following command in PowerShell which I want to see a list of versions for a specific package, but I get an error.

```
Find-Package -Name "UmbracoCms" -AllVersions
```

> Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'UmbracoCms'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.

Running `Get-PackageSource` gives me:

```
Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            True       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

What is the problem? Where is my mistake?

I tried to get also for other packages like `nunit` and get the same thing..

Comment: Try the API v2 source: find-package -name "UmbracoCms" -AllVersions -Source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/"

Comment: Did you try your command before post it ? I tried myself and same error occur

Comment: Yep. It works for me. But it doesn't work with v3 API, where I get the same error as yours.

Comment: Well, something funny: the feed link has been butchered in my first comment above. It should be: www.nuget.org/api/v2/, precedeed with https colon slash slash. See nuget feed location here: https://www.nuget.org/ and pick the v2 link.

Comment: Yesh, it works ! Post above comment in answer and I will accept it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [nuget feed v2](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2) instead of your [nuget feed v3](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) as your package source.

So, this works:

```
find-package -name "UmbracoCms" -AllVersions -Source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2"
```