# Unable to find dependent package(s) (System.Runtime)

Tags: powershell, nuget, magick.net

I'm having some trouble understanding what is wrong.

I'm using Windows Powershell Version: 5.1.18362.628

I expected 'Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU' to install.

```
PS C:\Users\gtamm\Source\Repos> Find-Package System.Runtime

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
System.Runtime                 4.1.2            nuget.org        Provides the fundamental primitives, classes and base classes that define commonly-used value and reference data types, events and event handlers, interfaces, attribute...


PS C:\Users\gtamm\Source\Repos> Install-Package System.Runtime

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'nuget.org'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms    3.1.0            nuget.org        Provides runtime information required to resolve target framework, platform, and runtime specific implementations of .NETCore packages. ...
Microsoft.NETCore.Targets      3.1.0            nuget.org        Provides supporting infrastructure for portable projects: support identifiers that define framework and runtime for support targets and packages that reference the mini...
System.Runtime                 4.1.2            nuget.org        Provides the fundamental primitives, classes and base classes that define commonly-used value and reference data types, events and event handlers, interfaces, attribute...


PS C:\Users\gtamm\Source\Repos>  Install-Package -Scope AllUsers -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Name 'Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU'

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'nuget.org'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
Install-Package : Unable to find dependent package(s) (System.Runtime)
At line:1 char:2
+  Install-Package -Scope AllUsers -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Name 'Magick. ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Runtime:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToFindDependencyPackage,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345128/2724376

This indicated to me that NuGet might be updated when I had installed Powershell 7

The solution for me is to specify the nuget v2 API instead of the now default of v3.

```
if($PSVersionTable.'PSVersion'.Major -eq 5) {
    Install-Package -Name "Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU" -Source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2"
} else {
    Install-Package -ProviderName "NuGet" -Name "Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is messing with your lookup on your system. Example of my system ...

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | 
Select-Object -Property Caption, BuildNumber, Version

<#
# Results

Caption                  BuildNumber Version   
-------                  ----------- -------   
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 18363       10.0.18363
#>

$PSVersionTable
<#
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628                                                                                                                                       
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.628}                                                                                                            
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.628                                                                                                                                      
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
#>

Find-Package -Name 'System.Runtime' | 
Format-List
<#
# Results

FastPackageReference : $bnVnZXQub3Jn\U3lzdGVtLlJ1bnRpbWU=\NC4zLjE=\
ProviderName         : NuGet
Source               : nuget.org
Status               : Available
SearchKey            : System.Runtime
FullPath             : 
PackageFilename      : System.Runtime.4.3.1.nupkg
FromTrustedSource    : False
Summary              : Provides the fundamental primitives, classes and bas...
#>
```

Though I am not sure, why you'd need to install this as this is part of Windows .Net full/core, thus already on your machine.

```
Find-Package -Name 'Magick.NET*'
<#
# Results

----                           -------          ------           -------                                                                                                           
Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU          7.15.4           nuget.org        A .NET API to the ImageMagick image-processing library for Desktop and Web.                                       
Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU           7.15.4           nuget.org        A .NET API to the ImageMagick image-processing library for Desktop and Web.                                       
Magick.NET-Q16-x64             7.15.4           nuget.org        A .NET API to the ImageMagick image-processing library for Desktop and Web.                                       
...
#>
```

***Update based on your response***

Try downloading / Saving it locally and manually...

```
Find-Package -Name 'Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU' | Save-Module -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Force
```

...then installing

```
 Install-Module -Name 'Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU' -Force
```

Comment: The command you are showing work fine at my end.
it goes wrong when you try to install 'Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU'.