# Getting an error when I try to install 'itext7' package from nuget

Tags: powershell, nuget

I can find the package with `Find-Package -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Name 'itext7'`:

```
Name Version Source Summary  
---- ------- ------ -------  
itext7 8.0.2 nuget.org iText for .NET is a library for PDF generation written entirely in C# for the .NET platform.
```

When I try to install it with `Find-Package -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Name 'itext7'| Install-Package -Destination C:/Temp`, it waits for about 40 seconds then, throws this error:

```
 Install-Package: Unable to find dependent package(s) (System.Reflection)
```

I searched around for what it means and possible solutions. This question, [Unable to find dependent package(s) (System.Runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564833/unable-to-find-dependent-packages-system-runtime), suggests the following worked for them:

```
find-package -name itext7 -Source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" | Install-Package -Destination c:\temp
```

but this also throws an error:

```
Install-Package: Dependency loop detected for package 'itext7'.
```

Of which I have not been able to find a solution for. Has anyone come across this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PowerShell, as of v7.4.0, lacks direct integration with NuGet packages, as evidenced not only by the "dependency loop" error you ran into: Even when an installation succeeds, loading the relevant assembly doesn't always load its dependencies, which requires a .NET SDK-based workaround (which also bypasses the "dependency loop" problem). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537273/45375) for more information.

Comment: I see so what is actually happening with `Install-Package` is that after downloading the files from Nuget, it also loads the dll into the current session, I was not aware of that all. I understand slightly better now. I will read the answer you linked to and see. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, but `Install-Package` does _not_ automatically load the assembly. In fact, you need to discover the relevant assembly file inside the downloaded package yourself, and even then loading may not work, due to missing dependencies.

Comment: Aaah, I will cross out that erroneous understanding on my part then. Cheers!